# UPBGE physics does not consider object deformation after starting

Tags: game-engine, physics, curve-modifier

I'm starting using UPBGE and I'm facing an issue with the physics engine behaviour. It seems that the engine does consider the Static objects as they are when starting the game.
For example, in this model, I have a basic conveyor on a loop, 2 dynamic cubes and a diverting cube.
[image]

When I press "F" the conveyor goes forward. Both cubes are travelling with the conveyor which is fine. The left cube is diverted as planned (big cube is a diverter applying a force on Y axis to objects travelling through it).
But the right cube continues as if it's still on the conveyor. It looks like that in the "engine's brain" the conveyor is translating and not following the curve (and so being inconsistent with the display).
[image]

I've tried several ways to make the conveyor move forward :

- Using brick logic to translate it along the curve
- Baking the animation into action and playing it using logic nodes
- Using a GeoNode to replace the curve modifier and driving one of the the GeoNode value from Logic Node

Nothing worked. It's like the deformation is not taken into account by the physics engine once the game is started.

Could someone confirm it's impossible to do what I want to do so I can stop trying. I want to see my right cube falling from the conveyor...

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10N-XxvfPBF5Kda2bdIJfW3t8v1NE7WaZ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Native Blender (which is mostly discussed here) no longer includes the Game Engine which has been a seperate project since it was removed from Blender 2.8 over 2 years ago. You'll probably get a more prompt answer if you tag your question 'upbge' or ask in one of the other UPBGE forums [here](https://upbge.org/#/community).

Comment: i would recommend asking on blenderartists.org